# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/(n!)^{2/n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I'm trying to investigate the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n!)^{2/n}}$

I know that $n!\geq (n/2)^{n/2+1}$ for all $n\geq 1$, and so after taking $2/n$ to both sides, I obtain:
$$n!^{2/n}\geq (n/2)^{1+2/n}$$
and thus:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n!)^{2/n}}\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n/2)^{1+2/n}}$$

But I'm not sure how to proceed after this, particularly because I think the sum on the right diverges.

Comment: use Stirling to conclude that denominator is roughly $n^2$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $$e^n = 1+\frac{n}{1!}+\frac{n^2}{2!}+\cdots + \frac{n^n}{n!}+\cdots > \frac{n^n}{n!}$$

Then $$\frac{1}{n!}< \frac{e^n}{n^n}$$ so
$$\frac{1}{n!^{2/n}} < \frac{e^2}{n^2}$$

and probably you can take it from here.